# View Pager contents not showing

Tags: android

On my Home Fragment it contains

- ScrollView

  - LinearLayout
  - RecycleView
  - LinearLayout

    - TabsLayout
    - ViewPager
    - TextView (Just to test if the height of ViewPager was updated)

When opening the home screen it will show the Recycle View, Tabs Layout and Text View does not include the View Pager (I did confirm that the adapter was executed properly but the content does not show)

- I did try to remove the visibility of the RecycleView and after that
  the ViewPager Contents shows up.

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/item_listing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_categories_content"/>
        <include
            layout="@layout/fragment_home_news_events"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**fragment_home_news_events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_margin"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_home_inner_tabs">
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_home_inner_tabs_content">
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_label_status"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**When the RecycleView is visible**
[image: When the RecycleView is visible]

**When the RecycleView is not visible**
[image: When the RecycleView is not visible]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have RecyclerView with include of another layout (fragment_home_news_events) the two had match_parent in height :(

try to fix height to fragment_home_news_events not match_parent.

or

put the height 0dp for both RecyclerView and fragment_home_news_events but with weight 1.

Comment: Thank youu!!! I did try to put a fixed height on the `fragment_home_news_events` (500dp) and it worked..
Note: using `wrap_content` won't fixed the issue. It should be a fixed height